# How to avoid using `this` pointer in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, this

I am reading about [prototipcal inheritance](http://aaditmshah.github.io/why-prototypal-inheritance-matters/#constructors_vs_prototypes). There, and from elsewhere, I am learning this style of avoiding classical inheritance which I am still digesting.

One aspect that still puzzles me, though, is the `this` pointer, which is said to cause confusion for many like myself who come from classic OO languages. (If I were to avoid classic inheritance, shouldn't I be avoiding `this` as well?
)

After some reading, I realize that *the `this` pointer is defined not at the time of object/function definition (as in C++) but rather at the site of function call.* The `this` pointer seems (to me) like a dangling pointer whose target depends on where/how you use it.

Using an example in the linked blog article about extending objects, can someone help explain the following:

Can we avoid using `this` or replacing it with explicit object reference?

A related question is, is the `this` pointer necessary if I only use prototypical inheritance?

Example from the blog:

> It would be nice to combine these two operations into one, ... and
>   extend it with new properties. This operation, called extend, can be
>   implemented as a function:

```
 1 Object.prototype.extend = function (extension) {
 2     var hasOwnProperty = Object.hasOwnProperty;
 3     var object = Object.create(this);
 4 
 5     for (var property in extension)
 6         if (hasOwnProperty.call(extension, property) ||
 7             typeof object[property] === "undefined")
 8                 object[property] = extension[property];
 9 
10     return object;
11 };
```

> Using the above extend function we can rewrite the code for square as
>   follows:

```
1 var square = rectangle.extend({
2     create: function (side) {
3         return rectangle.create.call(this, side, side);
4     }
5 });
6 
7 var sq = square.create(5);
8 
9 alert(sq.area());
```

Note, `this` is used in line 3 of both code segments.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid `this` completely, then you should step away from creating methods that act on the object they are applied on, meaning that you should not have method calls like `obj.method()`, where `method` needs to use the state of `obj` in some way.

So the effect of the following should be the same as `obj.method()`:

```
var method = obj.method;
method();
```

In places where the above would fail, you'll need to refactor the code, so that you can in principle use it like this without problems:

```
var method = obj1.method;
method(obj2); // apply method on obj2
```

So, in general you'll need to create utility functions that take one more argument: the object to apply the logic on.

In your case this would mean that you don't define `extend` on `Object.prototype` (which is [considered bad practice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#Bad_practice_Extension_of_native_prototypes) anyway), but on `Object` itself, and give it the extra source object parameter. This is also how many native methods are defined, like [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), et al.  Also the definition of `rectangle` will need some changes to make it work without ever using `this`:

```js
Object.extend = function (source, extension) {
    var hasOwnProperty = Object.hasOwnProperty;
    var object = Object.create(source);
 
    for (var property in extension)
        if (hasOwnProperty.call(extension, property) ||
            typeof object[property] === "undefined")
                object[property] = extension[property];

    return object;
};

var rectangle = {
    create: function (width, height) {
        var self = {
            width: width,
            height: height,
            area: function () {
                return self.width * self.height;
            }
        };
        return self;
    }
};

var square = Object.extend(rectangle, {
    create: function (side) {
        return rectangle.create(side, side);
    }
});

var sq = square.create(5);

console.log(sq.area());
```

As you have realised, there are lots of ways to work with objects and implement some form of inheritance in JavaScript, and each has its pros and cons.